# Query inside while loop of another query

Tags: php, mysqli

My code here doesn't works. I don't know why. I followed other posts solutions regarding this. Could you please help me find the error on this? The inside query has error and not updating at all. Thank you so much.

The pef_table has multiple record based on the single record from the std_booking table. And I'm trying to concat the column I wanted to insert(update query) in the std_booking table based on 'cs' on the first query.

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT cs FROM std_booking");
if($result1->num_rows>0){
    while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
        $cs = $row1['cs'];

        $pefDocConcat = "";
        $pefRemConcat = "";

        /*updating std_booking PEFs*/   
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT pefDoc, pefRemarks FROM pef_temp WHERE con_stckr = '$cs'");

        if($result2->num_rows>0){
            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
                $pefDoc = $row2['pefDoc'];
                $pefRemarks = $row2['pefRemarks'];

                $pefDocConcat .= $pefDoc . "|";
                $pefRemConcat .= $pefRemarks . "|";
            }

            mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE INTO std_booking SET std_pefDocs = '".$pefDocConcat."', std_pefRemarks = '".$pefRemConcat."' WHERE cs = '$cs'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried to print the update query?

Comment: I doubt if its looping for the 2nd query.

Comment: `UPDATE INTO` - remove the "into", that's part of the INSERT syntax, not UPDATE. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html - that being said, you can probably reduce the number of queries here, using a `JOIN` with a single SELECT query.

Comment: @Qirel OMG. Thank you so much. I know the flow is right. Thanks bro, I think i just need to rest a bit. lol. Thanks again! Appreciated!

Comment: Happy to have helped ;-)